# 80's-90's sci-fi book set in a spaceship, involved a threesome between a dreamer, an energy vampire and a catlike character

Tags: story-identification, books, space

The book I am looking for was written in the mid 80’s to early 90’s. It had a simple cover dark in color and was about an inch thick.

It took place largely on a spaceship. The three main characters were in a threesome, one was a dreamer, the other was some kind of energy vampire the third was somewhat catlike.

Comment: Except the the "threesome" part, I was totally ready to say a book based on "Red Dwarf."  Rimmer does have a way of sucking the energy out of a room.

Comment: Are you sure about the "catlike" part?  Jacqueline Lichtenberg's Dreamspy has a dreamer (human male), a vampire (male) and a telepathic woman...